# How to undelete a module from a JEDI Version System project

Tags: delphi, version-control, jedi

I deleted, by mistake, a file (pas+dfm) from JEDI. How can I undelete? I don't want to lose the module history. I am using JEDI CLient 2.4.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I found that a way to do it is going on Project/Deserted Modules. Here there is the list of all the modules that are not in project anymore, and right clicking on them it is possible to "add to project" again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about JEDI VCS specifically, but with any other VCS like SubVersion+TortoiseSVN, you'd simply update the folder where the files were, and they'd come right back.